# download and online stream is not working in parallel

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, react-redux, parallel-processing, google-cloud-storage

We have encountered a problem, where we are downloading the video on my application home page and playing it in the videoPlayer page. Playing the video is getting stuck since download is in progress and the streaming request to google-cloud-bucket is in "pending" status(refer the screenshot).
As soon as download completes, video starts playing on videoPlayer page.

Can someone suggest any idea/solution for this usecase. There is an error message which is coming on console(on production) and on UI on local dev env.

Error Message: Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause().

[image]

Comment: can you briefly explain what are you trying to do and what issue are you facing from Google cloud storage side?

Comment: We are downloading a video (in listing page) and immediately trying to open corresponding item to play video file in application (in PlayerPage). Video file is in GCS bucket & we are generating signedurl to download/play. Playing the video is getting stuck since download is in progress and the streaming request to google-cloud-bucket is in "pending" status(in inspect->network tab

If i try to download some external video (non-GCS file) and try to play video - it doesnt affect playing capability.
As soon as it completes, video starts playing

Comment: @DivyaniYadav any suggestions here.

Comment: can you refer to these answers : [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71270309/15774176) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35949929/15774176) is it helpful? if not please share the Official documentation and the process that you are following up to download and stream

Comment: @DivyaniYadav, well I have the authenticated signed URL and using the Video component of react, I am assigning the URL to src attribute of Video tag.
Then player/browser is making request to google-bucket to fetch the video chunks. These request are in pending status If I play the video after downloading that video. There is no other handling or processing being done by me. It is all using Video component of react.